# how to retrive status value from $user?

Tags: php, laravel, status

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
        $user = User::findOrFail($user);
        return $user;
        //$arruser = $user->toArray();
      /*  if($user->status==0){
          Auth::logout();
          return redirect('login')->with('verify_info','Verify First');
        }*/
    }
```

$user returning--->

```
id 54
name "Rasul"
email "golam.rasul@gmail.com"
verify_token "BiOF8L8DJb"
status 0
created_at "2017-07-26 09:39:46"
updated_at "2017-07-26 09:39:46"
Problem is when i m trying to get value of status using
```

$user-> status
 it says Property [status] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `return $user` you get a collection
How about you get an object by `first()` , then get the property status.

Something like this :

```
    $user = User::findOrFail($user)->first();
    return $user;
```